# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac {\log({p_n}^{\frac 1n}-1)}{\log(p_n)}\right)$ equal to?

Tags: limits, prime-numbers

How can one prove that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac {\log({p_n}^{\frac 1n}-1)}{\log(p_n)}\right) = -1?$$

Here, $p_n$ is the $n$th prime and $\log$ is the natural logarithm. I tried the following:
$$ \log({p_n}^{\frac 1n}-1) \to -\log(p_n) $$
$$ {p_n}^{\frac 1n}-1 \to p_n^{-1} $$
$$ {p_n}^{\frac 1n + 1}-p_n \to 1 $$
But I am stuck there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $p_n \sim n \log{n}$ might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:
Use $p_n \approx n \log n$ which follows from the PNT

This becomes $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log((n \log n)^{1/n} - 1)}{\log(n \log n)}$$
Now you can apply L'Hopital and get your result.